# C++ Convert part of the Array into int

Tags: c++, char, int

I want to convert Part of `char array[100]` to `int`

I mean I want only the first 2 arrays `array[0]` and `array[1]`

I want to read the hex of the array into `int`

I mean if `array[0]=T` which corresponds to `0xC2`

I want that Value to be as `int` instead of `char`

```
uint8_t z;
z=static_cast<uint8_t>(buf[0]);
```

But I want to take value of `buf[1]` too not only `buf[0]`

`z` would be value of the 2 `buf[0]` and `buf[1]`

Comment: What programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to be sure because your question isn't very clear. But perhaps this is what you want

```
uint16_t z = *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(array);
```

Another possiblity is

```
uint16_t z = static_cast<uint8_t>(buf[0])*256 + static_cast<uint8_t>(buf[1]);
```

and another is

```
uint16_t z = static_cast<uint8_t>(buf[1])*256 + static_cast<uint8_t>(buf[0]);
```

Try them all, they differ only in what *endianness* they use. You should look that up.

One thing that is confusing me is that you say you want two bytes, but your `z` variable is declared as `uint8_t` which is one byte only. I changed it to `uint16_t`.

Comment: yes that 1 byte for 1 buf only,thanks this what i was searching for great one :)